# Default publish vs pick a publish target in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have two app service application and function apps [different solutions]. Both are developed using .Net core Visual Studio 2019.

I see different type of wizards for publish during publishing app service . This is creating confusion.

I would like to know, why there are different types of Wizards? Why in one solution its showing and other its not?

In general case, I can just click on publish and it will publish. However, in case of "pick a publish target" I need to download the publish profile and do "import profile". Will I need to take any extra care during "import profile" ? What are the difference between two types of publish? Which is the preferable way? Could anyone please help me understand this?

Any link/tutorial that will explain the step by step approach of "Pick a publish Profile" ? Thanks

Below screenshot shows, different wizard:

[image: General]

[image: Pick a target]

Answer (score 1):

In the first image, you have already created a publish profile. Hence, it just straight asking you to publish.

In the second case, you don't have a publish profile yet so it is asking you to Import or create a publish profile. You can also create a publish profile by selecting App Service instead of IIS, FTP etc and then once the profile is created it will work like in your first case. And off course, import a profile which again should only happen once and thereafter it should automatically use that profile.

Comment: The application is already published in Azure and I have been told to download the publish profile from different slots and use that publish profile for my future publish. Also, when I created the publish profile for the 1st time ( from VS publish) it did not show me "Pick a publish Target"

Comment: maybe it didnt show you because you selected publish as an app service. But anyways, once you select app service and them import the profile, it should not ask you this again. Right now it is asking you the target (which once you select as App service, it wont ask again). Creating a profile via VS Publish wizard or downloading it from Azure , in both cases you actually get the same profile with details like web publish setting, FTP publish settings etc.